What can be said about this recurrence relation?
Fix $\delta \in (0,1)$ and fix a positive integer $n$. Then consider the recurrence relation where $v_{n,n} = 0$ and
$$
v_{n,k} = v_{n,k+1} - \frac{(\delta^k+v_{n,k+1})(\delta^{k-1}+v_{n,k+1})}{\delta^{k-1} (2+\delta)} = \frac{-\delta^{1-k} v_{n,k+1}^2 + v_{n,k+1} - \delta^k}{2+\delta}
$$
I know it is written "backwards," sorry. I only care about the values $v_{n,k}$ for $k \in [0,n]$. I know there is very little chance of a closed form solution for $v_{n,k}$ since even with constant coefficients quadratic linear recurrence relations are quite difficult.
But I don't need a closed form solution, I just want to understand the limit below, where $k$ is a fixed value in $[0,n]$.
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} v_{n,k}
$$
Is there anything I can say about this limit? Things I already know include:

$v_{n,k} \in [-1,0]$ for all $n$ and $k$
$v_{n,k} <
    \frac{v_{n,k+1}}{2+\delta}$ because the quadratic and constant terms
are negative. So for a fixed $n$ the sequence $v_{n,0}, v_{n,1}, \ldots, v_{n,n-1}, v_{n,n}$ is strictly increasing.
Experimentally, it seems that the sequence $v_{0,k}, v_{1,k}, v_{3,k}, \ldots$ is decreasing. For example, with $\delta = 0.9$ and $k=0$ we get
\begin{align*}
v_{0,0} &\approx -0.4336 \\
v_{1,0} &\approx -0.4974 \\
v_{2,0} &\approx -0.5338
\end{align*}
and it continues to decrease at least for as long as my computer calculates.

